# How to remove redirection unexpected syntax errors

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am loading using Ubuntu for beagleboard-xm sd card partition so after last stage of partition I have entered a command like this `./omap3-mkcard.sh /dev/sdX` I have got

```
ti-lab@KILBY:~/angstrom-wrk$ ./omap3-mkcard.sh /dev/sdX 
./omap3-mkcard.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./omap3-mkcard.sh: line 1: `<HTML><HEAD>'
./omap3-mkcard.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
bash: ./omap3-mkcard.sh:: No such file or directory
```

So how can I rectify this problem please help me

Comment: Where did you get the `omap3-mkcard.sh` file? it looks like you may have downloaded it with HTML encoding instead of as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

steeldriver's comment makes sense. Given the line the error is on, it looks like you're trying to run an HTML file. Further I'm assuming you ran something like:

```
wget http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded/tree/contrib/angstrom/omap3-mkcard.sh
chmod +x omap3-mkcard.sh
./omap3-mkcard.sh ...
```

If you look at the source of that:

```
wget -O- http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded/tree/contrib/angstrom/omap3-mkcard.sh | less
```

... You'll see that it's HTML, not the bash script you wanted.

In future note that there's a "plain" link above the code (Github calls it "raw"). This will output a HTML-free plaintext version of the file that cau be `wget`-ted. So for your commands:

```
rm omap3-mkcard.sh  # nuke the old copy
wget http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded/plain/contrib/angstrom/omap3-mkcard.sh
chmod +x omap3-mkcard.sh
./omap3-mkcard.sh ...
```

Either that or you open `omap3-mkcard.sh` and replace it with a copy-paste from the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to put quotes **"** around all your HTML tags in your script as they also have a special meaning to the shell.

See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html